# stuck with node.js Readline module

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

I am at very entry level with Node.js and JavaScript , i want to read from a txt file line by line and print every single line with adjusted time interval , i found this module which helped me to read lines "https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html" .
but my code publish all lines once , i want to wait seconds between lines 
i added setTimeout function and tried alot of configration with no vail . Thanks

```
     const readline = require('readline');
     const fs = require('fs');
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream(process.cwd() +'/sample.txt')  
 });

 rl.on('line', function(input){
  rl.pause();
  console.log(input);

   setTimeout(() => {
     rl.resume();
    }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses a queue. Each time a line is read, it's added to a queue which is consumed line per line every 5 seconds.

```
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(process.cwd() + '/sample.txt')
});

var queue = [];

setInterval(function () {
    if (queue.length > 0) {
        var item == queue.shift();
        console.log(item);
    }
}, 5000);

rl.on('line', function(input) {
    queue.push(input);
});
```

In case your queue gets very large, you can pause, and resume again when the length is lower.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with synchronous executor [nsynjs](https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs):

```
var nsynjs = require('nsynjs');

// following 2 files can be found in nsynjs package
var textFile = require('./wrappers/nodeReadline').textFile;
var wait = require('./wrappers/nsynWait').nsynWait;

function process(textFile,wait) {
    var fh = new textFile();
    fh.open('../data/lorem.txt');
    var s, i = 0;
    while (typeof(s = fh.readLine(nsynjsCtx).data) != 'undefined')
    {
        if(s)
            console.log(s);
        else
            console.log("<empty line>");
        wait(nsynjsCtx,1000);
    }
    fh.close();
}

var ctx = nsynjs.run(process,{},textFile,wait,function () {
    console.log('done');
});
```

Full working example can be found here: https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs/blob/master/examples/node-readline/index.js